# How to use UNION type to receive different types in one CPN place?

Tags: petri-net, cpn-tools

I want to use a union in a way a place can receive two different types of "request", in my Coloured Petri Net model.

I have the following declarations:

```
colset AUTHENTICATION = product INT * STRING;
colset REQUEST_PUB = product AUTHENTICATION * STRING * REAL;
colset REQUEST_SUB = product AUTHENTICATION * STRING * INT;
colset REQUEST_PUBSUB = union REQUEST_PUB + REQUEST_SUB;
```

I have the following configuration:

Transition ------> Place (REQUEST_PUBSUB) <------ Transition

The right transition is sending `((int, string), string, real)` and the left transition is sending `((int, string), string, int)`. Since the place is of type `REQUEST_PUBSUB`, which is a union of `REQUEST_PUB` and `REQUEST_SUB`, theoretically this should work, once `((int, string), string, real)` is clearly a valid `REQUEST_PUB` and `((int, string), string, int)` is clearly a valid `REQUEST_SUB`.

But this is not working and I am receiving the following errors:

> Error: expression doesn't match constraint [tycon mismatch]
>     expression: (INT * STRING) * STRING * REAL
>     constraint: REQUEST_PUBSUB ms
>     in expression ((int, string), string, real): REQUEST_PUBSUB ms
>     Elaborate failure

And

> Error: expression doesn't match constraint [tycon mismatch]
>     expression: (INT * STRING) * STRING * INT
>     constraint: REQUEST_PUBSUB ms
>     in expression ((int, string), string, int): REQUEST_PUBSUB ms
>     Elaborate failure

Can anyone help me with this? I think the description is clear, but I can complement it with more information if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it specifying the identifiers for the union types:

```
colset REQUEST_PUBSUB = union pub_req:REQUEST_PUB + sub_req:REQUEST_SUB;
```

Then, for right transition arc I used `pub_req((int, string), string, real)` and for left transition arc I used `sub_req((int, string), string, int)`.